# print string array from data table row based on a string match

Tags: c#, datatable

how can I print a specific data row that contains a string array based on a string search match? I have a data table that contains specific items ("Key"), and each Key Item has specific/different "Info" assigned to it. the "Info" row contains a string array. I need to retrieve the "Info" array, based on its related "Key".. and possibly iterate through each info item and perform other actions to it.

I created a datatable from a json file (using newtonsoft.json) that looks like this..

```
{
  "Tables": [
    {
      "Key": "Tbl-01",
      "Info": ["TopCoat","BotCoat","EndPrep","Room","Rotation Angle","KeyPoint"],
      "Dim": ["Length","Diameter"]
    },
    {
      "Key": "Tbl-45",
      "Info": ["TopCoat","EndPrep","KeyPoint"],
      "Dim": ["Length","Diameter"]
    },
    {
      "Key": "Tbl-89",
      "Info": ["BotCoat","EndPrep","X","Y","Z"],
      "Dim": ["Length","Diameter"]
    }
  ],
  "Chairs": [
    {
      "Key": "Ch-9",
      "Info": ["SeatCover","Rotation Angle","KeyPoint"],
      "Dim": ["Width"]
    },
    {
      "Key": "Ch-19",
      "Info": ["SeatCover","FootCovers","Room","Mfr"],
      "Dim": ["Length","Width"]
    },
    {
      "Key": "Ch-01",
      "Info": ["SeatCover","FootCovers","Placement Point"],
      "Dim": ["Length","Width"]
    }
  ]  
}
```

my C# code looks like this...

````
            string PropSource = @"C:\Users\username\Desktop\Furniture.json";
            string Propmap = File.ReadAllText(PropSource);

            DataSet dataset = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<DataSet>(Propmap);
            foreach (DataTable dt in dataset.Tables)
            {
               // Console.WriteLine(dt.TableName);
               foreach (DataRow dr in dt.Rows)
                {
                    if (dr["Key"].ToString() == "Ch-9")
                    {
                        //not sure what to do here to get the array of "info" items related to Ch-9, 
                        and iterate through the array items.
                    }
                }
            }```
````